# Dont see spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive and spring-boot-starter-webflux dependency in maven

Tags: java, spring, reactive

I am following the Spring Reactive Example from the link: https://github.com/mohitsinha/tutorials/blob/master/spring-boot-webflux-reactive-mongo/build.gradle. The same project I am developing using the maven, but I dont see below maven dependency present. What should I used ?

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb-reactive')
```

I am getting the below error:

```
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.security:spring-security-webflux:jar is missing. @ line 48, column 15

        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:422)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.collectProjects(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:419)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.getProjectsForMavenReactor(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:410)
        at org.apache.maven.graph.DefaultGraphBuilder.build(DefaultGraphBuilder.java:83)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.buildGraph(DefaultMaven.java:491)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:219)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
```

and here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.spring.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-webflux-reactive-mongo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>spring-boot-webflux-reactive-mongo</name>
    <description></description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.flapdoodle.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Basically maven dependency for `org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.ReactiveMongoRepository`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like you are using  spring boot `1.5.8.RELEASE` And the link you provided uses `2.0.0.M2`, but according to [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-webflux) there is no `Spring Boot WebFlux Starter` for `1.5.8.RELEASE` version. As a result you are getting

```
version for org.springframework.security:spring-security-webflux:jar is missing
```

You can manually add a [version](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webflux), but this can probably cause invalid configuration problems, so just upgrade your pom to spring boot `2.0.0.M2` or higher

Comment: Hey, I'm unable to give spring-boot-starter-parent to 2.0.0.M2 or higher, because I get some error. I need to make this working with the 1.5.8.RELEASE. Now I only got the below error, `The import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions.nest cannot be resolved`

Comment: @Prateek you need to search for the missing package https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/ and include it in pom. But i'm not even sure that this will work at the end, because WebFlux support is actually `Spring 5.0.0` feature and you are trying to integrate in in  `spring boot 1.5.8` that uses `Spring 4.3.12.RELEASE` There is a high chance you will need to implement everything yourself

Comment: @Prateek i think Webflux before 5.0 was Spring Reactive Web so you should probably look in this direction. Take a look https://spring.io/blog/2016/06/13/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-ii-writing-some-code and part 3 https://spring.io/blog/2016/07/20/notes-on-reactive-programming-part-iii-a-simple-http-server-application